# Mock FeignClient response

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

It's possible to mock response FeignClient via MockRestServiceServer(restTemplate)? 
This example dosn't work:

**Application.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**TicketService.class**

```
@FeignClient("ws")
public interface TicketService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tickets/")
    List<Ticket> findAllTickets();

}
```

**TestConfig.class**

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

**MyTest.class**

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, properties = {"ws.ribbon.listOfServers:example.com"})
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    DispatcherService dispatcherService; // service where the execution of the method TicketService.findAllTickets();

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void ticket() {
        mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://example.com/tickets/"))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withSuccess(new ClassPathResource("tickets.json"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        dispatcherService.run();
    }
}
```

But going a request to the real server example.com.

Comment: Feign clients are interfaces. The best approach is generally to just mock the interface directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment I know 2 good approaches:

1. Use wiremock library (for Spring Boot i use **spring-cloud-contract-wiremock**)
2. Mockito (i use **@MockBean**)